# Find number of neighbours in 2D array using convolve2d

Tags: python, scipy, 2d

I have a 2-dimensional lattice (L*L) with fixed boundaries and considering N-S-W-E sites as 4 neighbours to each site. Each site is assigned an float value. For each site I am calculating average of values of its neighbouring sites added to its own value. I want to solve this using convolv2d from scipy.signal. Following is my code:

```
# xi_out = constant1*xi + constant2*(sum of xi's neighbours)/no_of_xi's_neighbours

import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

L = 6  # each side of 2D lattice
a, b = (0.1, 0.5) # two constants
arr = np.random.rand(L, L) # example 2D array
# (3,3) window representing 4 neighbours which slides over 'arr'
kernel = np.array([[0, b, 0],
                   [b, a, b],
                   [0, b, 0]])
neighbors_sum = convolve2d(arr, kernel, mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
print(neighbors_sum)
```

I can not find a way to divide sum of neighbouring values for each site by number of its neighbours.

In following manner I can find number of neighbours for each site but do not know how to incorporate these values into 'result'. Can somebody suggest me how can I achieve that or is there a simpler in-built method in convolve2d to do that ?

```
arr = np.ones((L,L), dtype=np.int)
kernel = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0]])
neighbors_count = convolve2d(arr, kernel, mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
print(neighbors_count)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.signal import convolve2d

L = 6
a, b = 0.1, 0.5

arr = np.random.rand(L, L)
arrb = arr.astype(bool)
kernel = np.array([[0, 1, 0],
                   [1, 0, 1],
                   [0, 1, 0]])

neighbors_sum = convolve2d(arr, kernel, mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
neighbors_count = convolve2d(arrb, kernel, mode='same', boundary='fill', fillvalue=0)
neighbors_mean = np.divide(neighbors_sum, neighbors_count)
res = a * arr + b * neighbors_mean
print(res)
```

Answer (score 0):

To divide one array by another, element-by-element, use `np.divide`:

```
np.divide(result, neighbours_count)
```

Looks like this is all that needs to be added to your code; I think it's pretty good as is.

Generally, to find a weighted average of some sort, one can do the following:

1. Perform summation with weights on the input array.
2. Perform the same on the array of ones, of the same size as the input.
3. Divide the result of 1 by the result of 2.

Comment: You are right except to achieve this I have to have a common `kernel` by taking `kernel[1,1]=0`, so as to exclude the site's value itself from its neighbors.